# Selected value not getting selected in Select2+Angular

Tags: angularjs, select, dropdown, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 dropdown in my project. While trying to get the selected value getting selected value with "number" string attached. Like "number:2. Instead of just "2".

Screen shot of the HTML code generated in the brower -

[image]

I have used the following code for populating the dropdown.

```
                                <select id="ddlTripTrailerNo" class="select5"
                                        ng-model="result.TripDetails.TrailerID"
                                        ng-options="option.TrailerID as option.TrailerNo for option in trailerNos">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" value="any">Choose a Subject</option>
                                </select>
```

I have checked for solutions but unable to find any. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ddlTripTrailerNo" [(ngModel)]="result.TripDetails.TrailerID" class="form-control">
       <option
           *ngFor="let option of optionList"
           id="OPTION_{{ option.id }}"
           [value]="option.id"
           >
              {{ option.TrailerNo }}
         </option>
 </select>
```

Here I used option list as an example instead of using your iterated list. you can refer this and adopt in to your code base. Befor code html file you need to import **MatFormFieldModule** in you module.ts. I have used **[(ngModel)]** for two way data binding. You can refer this for more information of **select**.
[enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)